# how can i get the return value of fetch method to be put in an alert?

Tags: json, react-native, fetch

I am trying to do a register and when I submit the form, the app should show an alert from the return of the service. here is the return of the service :

```
{
    "Result": {
        "retVal": "20404|Save Successed!"
    }
}
```

and the fetch code is as below :

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ save: 
    { NoKTP: '1234123412341234',
      Nama: 'Rondi',
      Email: 'rondi@rocketmail.com',
      Password: '123qwert',
      NoTelp: '779977',
      NoHP: '081112222345' } 
  })
})
.then( (response) => response.json())
.then( (responseJson) => {
  Alert.alert("respon : " + responseJson.retVal)
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

but when I run the app, the alert shows me
"respon : undefined"

how can I get the retVal value to show in the alert?
can anybody help me? thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Alert.alert("respon : " + responseJson.retVal);
```

to

```
Alert.alert("respon : " + responseJson);
```

and try

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to change:

```
Alert.alert("respon : " + responseJson.retVal)
```

to:

```
Alert.alert("respon : " + responseJson.Result.retVal)
```

In order to match the format of your response :)

Comment: i have tried to change and add Result.. but it throws me an error with red background saying "undefined is not an object"